# como puedo pasar variables bash a sql?

Tags: mysql, bash

Tengo un script en bash pero en que en cierto punto necesito ejecutar muchas consultas, como el nombre de la base de datos y el prefijo de la tabla son variables.

Yo lo tengo así:

```
mysql -u root -e "INSERT INTO $1.$6TABLA ... ... ..;"
```

Funciona bien pero el script ya es enorme como de 2000 lineas y hago muchos cierres y llamadas a sql.
Por ello, quiero poner todas las consultas en un archivo .sql. Funciona, pero las variables $1.$6 se pierden.

```
mysql -u root -p $1< /var/www/consultas.sql
```

y me responde:

```
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 2: Table '$1.$6....' doesn't exist
```

Ya que las variables no las interpreta dentro del archivo sql como puedo corregir ya sea pasar las variables a el .sql o haciendo un `replace` en el archivo

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Si tus variables están exportadas (`export var`), puedes usar el `envsubst`:

```
mysql -u root -e $(envsubst < /var/www/consultas.sql)
```

Por ejemplo:

```
$ export foo=bar
$ cat file
La variable foo contiene: $foo
$ envsubst < file
La variable foo contiene: bar
```

Si no están exportadas, puedes intentar identificar todas las variables en el fichero y exportarlas:

```
. <(grep -oP '\$\S+' /var/www/consultas.sql | sed 's/\$/export /')
```